# jsonb_set pass variable value instead of static in procedure

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, jsonb

[image]Need help to get jsob_set working under PostgreSQL procedure,
Fetching records from child table and updating parent table's json fields value. 
Assigning selected value to the variable and adding it to jsonb_set under value,
e.g

> jsonb_set(jsonFieldOfDb,'{json_Column}',jsonVariable,true);

Where jsonVariable is my selected value from second table.
For more detail please look at screenshot attached.

Comment: did you try explicitly casting path to text[] and `jsonVariable` to jsonb?.. and are you running at least 9.5?..

Answer (score 4):

You might need to cast the path & `jsonVariable` to `text[]` and `jsonb`

`jsonb_set(jsonFieldOfDb,'{json_Column}'::text[],jsonVariable::jsonb,true)`

if your `jsonVariable` is just a plain string, you might need to quote them as well

`jsonb_set(jsonFieldOfDb,'{json_Column}'::text[],('"' || jsonVariable || '"')::jsonb, true)`

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Yurui's answer, if you want to set a dynamic value other than string, you can convert the dynamic variable to jsonb by using `to_jsonb` function like this:

```
UPDATE event AS e 
SET source_json = jsonb_set(source_json, '{consumerId}'::text[], to_jsonb(p.promoter_id)) 
FROM promoter AS p 
WHERE e.id = p.event_id and p.app_id in ('123');
```